# Como concatenar valores de RadioButtons em Razor/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, razor

Estou com uma dúvida e está meio difícil encontrar uma forma prática de resolver.

Eu criei um `groupbox` com 10 `radiobuttons`. Gostaria de saber a melhor prática para que quando o usuário marcar um deles eu armazene esse valor em uma variável para que eu possa concatenar esses valores com mais 2 grupos.

Exemplo:

`RadioButton1` do `groupbox1` vale 1, o `RadioButton` da `groupbox2` vale 2.

Ele deverá pegar os números e colocar um em cada variável para que eu possa concatenar lado a lado resultando em (12) e não (3), e após isso fazer um cálculo de potência usando o valor do 3º groupbox.

Comment: Você quer em Razor?

Comment: Sou meio novo em c# e desconheço Razor. eu editei o titulo da pergunta.
Mas o caso é que preciso concatenar dois valores um de cada raddiobutton  e elevar a potencia de um valor do raddiobutton da ultima groupbox.
Porem cada  raddiobutton deve conter um valor por exemplo.
Raddiobutton1 tem que armazenar o valor 10;
então não consigo fazer com apenas true ou false;
não sei se consegui me expressar corretamente.

Comment: Isto pode ser resolvido por [tag:javascript]. Editei sua pergunta para atingir o público adequado.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Vou começar a formatar o texto da mesma forma que você fez.
Lamento a minha inexperiência no stackoverflow.

Comment: @cigano a pergunta se refere a c# mesmo e não html e javascript.

Comment: Na verdade o foco da pergunta não é no [tag:c#]. Predominantemente o cálculo que você precisa é um comportamento de cliente, resolvível por [tag:javascript]. C# pode acabar entrando depois, mas não agora.

Comment: Vou tentar explicar o que estou tentando fazer.
É um pequeno programa para calcular o valor do componente eletrônico resistor.
Cada resistor tem um valor de resistência diferente e o seu valor é indicado por um código de cores assim como a sua tolerância.
a `groupbox1` representa a primeira faixa de cor do resistor a    `groupbox2` representa a segunda faixa de cor e a    `groupbox3` representa o seu multiplicador eu criei um    form e inseri esses componentes o caso é eu gostaria de saber a melhor syntax para resolver isso eu fiquei perdido pois em php seria muito fácil para eu fazer.

Comment: Então, como eu te disse e vou repetir: o comportamento dos `RadioGroups` deve ser calculado em tela. Pra mandar o resultado final pro Controller (no caso de uma aplicação MVC), é preciso que esses valores primeiro estejam calculados em tela.

Comment: Na verdade é só um `form` mesmo poderia ser algo bem simples e não uma aplicação MVC, mas agora entendi o que você quis dizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o @cigano falou a solução desse problema pode ser melhor em Javascript.

Segue exemplo usando HTML + Javascript com JQuery e o [JSFIDDLE funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/RHtWS/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Grupo 1 (Primeiro Dígito):</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="1"/> 1<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="2"/> 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo1" value="3"/> 3<br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Grupo 2 (Segundo dígito):</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="1"/> 1<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="2"/> 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo2" value="3"/> 3<br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Grupo 3 (Potencia):</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo3" value="1"/> 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo3" value="2"/> 3<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="grupo3" value="3"/> 3<br/>
    </fieldset>
    Resultado:
    <input type="text" id="txtResultado"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').on('click',CalculaResultado);
});

function CalculaResultado(oRadio){
    var grupo1 = $('input:radio[name="grupo1"]:checked').val();
    var grupo2 = $('input:radio[name="grupo2"]:checked').val();
    var grupo3 = $('input:radio[name="grupo3"]:checked').val();
    var resultado = parseInt(grupo1.toString() + grupo2.toString()) 
    resultado = Math.pow(resultado,parseInt(grupo3))
    if (!isNaN(resultado))
        $('#txtResultado').val(resultado);
    else 
        $('#txtResultado').val(0);
}
```